# What does ** mean?

Tags: solidity

I noticed this code in open zepplins contract:

```
  uint256 public constant INITIAL_SUPPLY = 10000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
```

I've never seen the double ** before. What does it mean?

Comment: FYI, the same syntax for exponentiation is used in many programming languages: Python, Ruby, Perl, Fortran, ADA, OCaml, ...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

from the [solidity documentation](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.3.1/types.html#integers) :

> Arithmetic operators: +, -, unary -, unary +, *, /, % (remainder), **
>   (exponentiation)

so : `a**b` is `a` to the power of `b` (i.e: `a*a*a*...*a` **b** times)

Answer (score 7):

`**` is `^`.
`2 ** 3` equals 8( ´ ▽ ` )

Answer (score 0):

This operator is used for exponentiation.